Filtering by Custom Taxonomy and Meta Fields in WordPress Produces Inconsistent Results
I'm building a custom WordPress theme for a job listing site, and I'm encountering an issue with filtering job listings. My site has custom post types and taxonomies for job categories and job types.
I can successfully filter by job categories using a query like:
http://example.com/?category=tech&salary_min=0&salary_max=50000
However, when I try to add a job type filter, the URL structure changes to:
http://example.com/job-type/freelance/?category=tech&salary_min=0&salary_max=50000
This causes the query to only filter by job type, ignoring other filters like job category and salary range.
Here’s a simplified version of the relevant code I'm using:
 
        <section class="job-listings">
           
            <?php
            $keywords = isset($_GET['keywords']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['keywords']) : '';
            $category = isset($_GET['category']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['category']) : '';
            $job_types = isset($_GET['job_type']) ? (array) $_GET['job_type'] : [];
            $date_posted = isset($_GET['date-posted']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['date-posted']) : '';
            $salary_min = isset($_GET['salary_min']) ? intval($_GET['salary_min']) : 0;
            $salary_max = isset($_GET['salary_max']) ? intval($_GET['salary_max']) : 20000;

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'job',
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
            );

            if ($keywords) {
                $args['s'] = $keywords;
            }

            $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

            if ($category) {
                $tax_query[] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'job_category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $category,
                );
            }

            if ($job_types) {
                $tax_query[] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'job_type',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => $job_types,
                );
            }

            if (!empty($tax_query)) {
                $args['tax_query'] = $tax_query;
            }

            if ($date_posted) {
                switch ($date_posted) {
                    case 'last-hour':
                        $args['date_query'] = array(
                            array(
                                'after' => '1 hour ago',
                            ),
                        );
                        break;
                    case 'last-24-hours':
                        $args['date_query'] = array(
                            array(
                                'after' => '24 hours ago',
                            ),
                        );
                        break;
                    case 'last-7-days':
                        $args['date_query'] = array(
                            array(
                                'after' => '7 days ago',
                            ),
                        );
                        break;
                    case 'last-14-days':
                        $args['date_query'] = array(
                            array(
                                'after' => '14 days ago',
                            ),
                        );
                        break;
                    case 'last-30-days':
                        $args['date_query'] = array(
                            array(
                                'after' => '30 days ago',
                            ),
                        );
                        break;
                }
            }

            $meta_query = array();

            if ($salary_min || $salary_max) {
                $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'     => '_job_salary',
                    'value'   => array($salary_min, $salary_max),
                    'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                );
            }

            if (!empty($meta_query)) {
                $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
            }

            $job_query = new WP_Query($args);

            if ($job_query->have_posts()) :
                while ($job_query->have_posts()) : $job_query->the_post();
                    $job_types = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'job_type');
                    $job_category = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'job_category');
                    $job_category_names = $job_category ? join(', ', wp_list_pluck($job_category, 'name')) : '';
                    $job_type_names = $job_types ? join(', ', wp_list_pluck($job_types, 'name')) : '';
                    $salary = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_job_salary', true);

                    $expiration_date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_job_expiration_date', true);
                    $is_available = strtotime($expiration_date) >= current_time('timestamp');
                    $salary_float = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $salary));

                    ?>

                    
                    <div class="job-card">
                    <div class="job-card-title">
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <span class="availablity <?php echo $is_available ? 'available' : 'not-available'; ?>">
                            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> <?php echo $is_available ? 'Available' : 'Not Available'; ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                        <div class="job-card-meta">
                            <p class="job-category"><i class="fi fi-rr-briefcase"></i><?php echo esc_html($job_category_names); ?></p>
                            <span><i class="fas fa-clock"></i> <?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' ago'; ?></span>
                            <p class="job-salary"><i class="fa fa-money"></i><?php echo esc_html($salary); ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                <?php endwhile;
            else :
                echo '<p>No jobs found</p>';
            endif;

            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
        </section>

Questions:
1-How can I ensure that all filters (job type, job category, salary range, etc.) work together without changing the URL structure?
2-Is there a way to keep all filters in the query string and avoid WordPress's default taxonomy URL handling?
3-What could be causing the issue where the job type filter overrides other filters?
